# Can I achieve this substitution with sed? (what does the unknown command: `+' mean)

Tags: regex, sed

I want to change lines of the format

```
ARR[6]=/var/dir1
ARR[7]=/var/dir2
```

to the fomat

```
ARR+=(/var/dir1)
ARR+=(/var/dir2)
```

I'm thinking about something like `sed -s /[.]=/+=/g` (which gives me: unknown command: `+'), but can not get it to work.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed 's/\[[0-9]*\]=\(.*\)/+=(\1)/' file
ARR+=(/var/dir1)
ARR+=(/var/dir2)
```

Or this awk:

```
awk -F '\\[[0-9]+\\]=' '{printf "%s+=(%s)%s", $1, $2, ORS}' file
ARR+=(/var/dir1)
ARR+=(/var/dir2)
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the bracket ?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/\[[^=]*=/+=(/;s/$/)/' YourFile
```

- no `g` in this case (only 1 occurence per line in your sample)
- posix compliant (`+` is a simple character in this mode)

Comment: Thank you. Good to see another way to do it. anubhava is really quick. so I accepted his answer

Comment: if his answer is good, that's fine even if another also good appear after and maybe better for your specfic case (but not necessary for someone else in a same style of problem).